# How to not display a certain error

Tags: search, options, error

My situation is, I have `set nowrapscan`, however now, when I hit the end of a file, it will display

```
E385: search hit BOTTOM without match for: \v^[^=]*(…
```

How can I avoid that from displaying? I used `help` but couldn't find anything about it.

Comment: :h silent might help

Comment: But it isn't practical for interactive use

Comment: I think you can't, if you don't want the message to be displayed, enable `wrapscan`. Otherwise it will be displayed, saying that you reached the end of the file.

Comment: Is there some way to the `wrapscan` setting for a specific search, like the `\c` and `\C` flags for case sensitive / insensitive search?

Answer (score 2):

you can use a custom command, if `:sil norm! n` is too much to type in interactive mode:

```
:com! :Nextmatch :sil :norm n
:nnoremap <silent> n :Nextmatch<cr>
```